# C# bot framework group chat information

Tags: c#, botframework, microsoft-teams

1- I have created Group in MS teams and added few members into group and had given group name as "[IT Bot Helper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8mMe.png)".
2- Now I have added our custom built Bot into this group and once BOT is added to this group OnTeamsMembersAddedAsync method is triggered in the C# code using BOT framework.

```
public class ITAssistantBot : TeamsActivityHandler
    {
        protected override async Task OnTeamsMembersAddedAsync(IList<TeamsChannelAccount> teamsMembersAdded, TeamInfo teamInfo, ITurnContext<IConversationUpdateActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            // Once Bot is added to teams group this method get triggers
            // I got all the members which is part of this member

        }
    }
```

3- OnTeamsMembersAddedAsync :- I also got the GroupId of this group using this turnContext.Activity.Conversation.Id but somehow I am not able to find the group name which is "IT Bot Helper".
Can someone help here to find the Group Name in this method.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, could you please add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so we can help you?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at the docs on [Teams contexts in bots](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/get-teams-context?tabs=dotnet) to see how to get data about a team. If the built-in functionality does not work for you, you could also look into using the [Microsoft Graph APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/use-the-api) instead. Graph lets you do many things that might not be natively supported in the Teams context.